# Is there a way to use single and double quotes in a jQuery variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to save this line in a variable:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more container_type="div" post_type="ps_resources" posts_per_page="6" pause="true" scroll="false" button_label="Load More"]'); ?>
```

So essentially, something like:

```
var loadMore = '<?php echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more container_type="div" post_type="ps_resources" posts_per_page="6" pause="true" scroll="false" button_label="Load More"]'); ?>';
```

Is this possible? I tried to escaping the double quotes but I am not having any luck.

Comment: yes there is, but using backticks allows using single and double quotes more easily together. \`"easy isn't it"\`

Comment: you need to escape the single quotes if you use single quotes

Comment: If you don't want to make if more unreadable escaping your quotes, I'd advise you to make it 2 statements. Store it in a php variable, then call `var loadMore = '<?php echo do_shortcode($myvariable); ?>';`

Comment: oh wait a minute, is this a php question or a javascript question? does the php snippet need to be evaluated, or you need the code literal string to be saved in the JS variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this.

These easiest is to use backticks (template literal), although you may need to compile this to ES5 for it to work on old browsers.

```
var loadMore = `<?php echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more container_type="div" post_type="ps_resources" posts_per_page="6" pause="true" scroll="false" button_label="Load More"]'); ?>`;
```

A second way is to escape the inner single quotes with `\`

```
var loadMore = '<?php echo do_shortcode(\'[ajax_load_more container_type="div" post_type="ps_resources" posts_per_page="6" pause="true" scroll="false" button_label="Load More"]\'); ?>';
```

A third way is to concatenate the strings:

```
var loadMore = '<?php echo do_shortcode('+"'"+'[ajax_load_more container_type="div" post_type="ps_resources" posts_per_page="6" pause="true" scroll="false" button_label="Load More"]'+"'"+'); ?>';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just do:

```
var loadMore = '<?php echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more container_type="div" post_type="ps_resources" posts_per_page="6" pause="true" scroll="false" button_label="Load More"]'); ?>';
```

You don't need to worry about the quote from js, once you hit `<?php` you are in PHP context, and it is not aware of the js quote.  The one thing you need to worry about is if there are any single quotes in the output of that function, so I would do:

```
var loadMore = '<?php echo str_replace("'", "\'", do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more container_type="div" post_type="ps_resources" posts_per_page="6" pause="true" scroll="false" button_label="Load More"]')); ?>';
```

Comment: No it doesnt: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/29e116c8fd6dbdd35afd06ac111a095bf785292d

Comment: thats php, the question is for javascript (containing a string which has php code)

Answer (score -2):

yes, you could do it using `` ` ``

```
var loadMore = `"' TEST'"`;
console.log(loadMore); // "' TEST'"
```

remember, inside the `` ` `` you can use `"` or `'` however you want.
so for your example, you could do:

```
var loadMore = `'<?php echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more container_type="div" post_type="ps_resources" posts_per_page="6" pause="true" scroll="false" button_label="Load More"]'); ?>'`;
```

Comment: that stores ' inside the string at the beggining and the end.

Comment: isn't that what he wants? @Noface

Comment: no, there is no `'` at the start and end of the line in their question. they are talking about the 2 `'`s within the string, whereas your answer has 4 `'`s